# ASP.NET: Function key shortcuts?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface, mainframe

I recently participated a project that replaced a mainframe system with a web (asp.net 2.0, VS2005) system.
The 3270-terminals are still much used and I respect the IMS/CICS/Cobol application designers for their work.

Users like the web application, but one thing they keep ask for is:
Functionkeys and shortcuts that navigates directly to different web forms.

Do you know a way to implement function key shortcuts in asp.net that will be like 3270 function key actions?

We are using asp:menu as a content in master-page, but asp:item does not support the accesskey attribute:

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="_siteMapDataSource" runat="server"  ShowStartingNode="False" />

<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server"  DataSourceID="_siteMapDataSource" Orientation="Horizontal">
</asp:Menu>
```

Update: 24.jan 09: I liked @John Sheehan answer. Will implement it with the jQuery support in ASP.Net 3.5 SP1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing specific to ASP.NET for this since you would need to handle it with JavaScript. The easiest way would be to use a jQuery plugin like [js-hotkeys](http://jshotkeys.googlepages.com/)

Answer (score 1):

you could take a look at the accesskey property as well...

Comment: Cross browser support for AccessKey is pretty poor

Comment: Is it? Can't say I'm a afan, but I'm pretty sure I've seen it working in both IE and Firefox. Haven't checked Safari, TBH